# Deleting trigger auto-deleted my script project

Tags: google-apps-script

When I deleted my only trigger (set to run daily) it took all of my script code with it!

When I now go into Tools/Script Editor it shows a blank project (not the saved code I've been working on for a month!)

Restoring previous versions of the spreadsheet doesn't work and I am using the account that I created it in.

I don't know where Sheets automatically stores the .gs files (they don't show on my Drive) but I'm hoping it still exists on their servers and it's just the link to it from the spreadsheet got broken and can be restored.

Please help as I do not want to start from scratch again

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If it's a container script and you have backed up the container then it's in there.  I don't think that they store files anywhere separately that I know of I hope somebody else knows for sure.

Comment: I didn't experiment ever a delete incident as you describe. Is quite possible that my suggestion is worthless but... did you check the version history [ File > See version history ] in the legacy editor? Did you check script.google.com looking for e.g. the deleted project?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that I use for backing up my files as both separate files and one  big JSON file. It won't help you fix your current problem but you can use to avoid it in the future and unlike backing up the entire spreadsheet and creating another unnecessary project, they get saved as ascii text files.

```
function saveScriptBackupsDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('backupscripts1'), 'Script Files Backup Dialog');
}

function scriptFilesBackup(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const scriptId = obj.script.trim();
  const folderId = obj.folder.trim();
  const saveJson = obj.saveJson;
  const saveFiles = obj.saveFiles;
  const fA = obj.selected;
 
  if (scriptId && folderId) {
    const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url1 = base + scriptId + "/content";
    const url2 = base + scriptId;
    const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
    const data1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
    const files = data1.files;
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options);
    const data2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
    let dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
    let subFolderName = Utilities.formatString('%s-%s', data2.title, dts);
    let subFolder = folder.createFolder(subFolderName);
    if (saveFiles) {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (file.source && file.name) {
          let ext = (file.type == "HTML") ? ".html" : ".gs";
          if (~fA.indexOf(file.name)) {
            subFolder.createFile(file.name + ext, file.source, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
          }
        }
      });
    }
    if (saveJson) {
      subFolder.createFile(subFolderName + '_JSON', res1, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
    }
  }
  return { "message": "Process Complete" };
}
```

The html for the dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
        input {margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;}
    #btn3,#btn4{display:none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="scr" name="script" size="60" placeholder="Enter Apps Script Id" onchange="getFileNames();" />
        <br /><input type="text" id="fldr" name="folder" size="60" placeholder="Enter Backup Folder Id" />
        <div id="shts"></div>
    <br /><input type="button" value="0" onClick="unCheckAll();" size="15" id="btn3" />
    <input type="button" value="1" onClick="checkAll();"size="15" id="btn4"/>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="files" name="saveFiles" checked /><label for="files">Save Files</label>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="json" name="saveJson" checked /><label for="json">Save JSON</label>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="backupFiles();" />
    </form>
        <script>
      function getFileNames() {
        const scriptid = document.getElementById("scr").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((names) => {
          document.getElementById('btn3').style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById('btn4').style.display = "inline";
          names.forEach((name,i) => {
           let br = document.createElement("br"); 
           let cb = document.createElement("input");
           cb.type = "checkbox";
           cb.id = `cb${i}`;
           cb.name = `cb${i}`;
           cb.className = "cbx";
           cb.value = `${name}`;
           cb.checked = true;
           let lbl = document.createElement("label");
           lbl.htmlFor = `cb${i}`;
           lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${name}`));
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(cb);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(lbl);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(br);
          });
        })
        .getAllFileNames({scriptId:scriptid}); 
      }
      function unCheckAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length);
        for(let i =0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
      function checkAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length)
        for(let i = 0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = true; 
        }
      }
      function backupFiles() {
        console.log('backupFiles');
        sObj = {};
        sObj.script = document.getElementById('scr').value;
        sObj.folder = document.getElementById('fldr').value;
        sObj.saveJson = document.getElementById('json').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.saveFiles = document.getElementById('files').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.selected = [];
        console.log("1");
        const cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        let selected = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<cbs.length; i++) {
          let cb = cbs[i];
          if(cb.checked) {
            sObj.selected.push(cb.value)
          } 
        }
        console.log("2");
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){google.script.host.close();})
        .scriptFilesBackup(sObj);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sObj));
      }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want the restore just ask.  I haven't used it that much I usually the file that I need and paste past it in.

Comment: Thanks for that. You would think I would have learned my lesson by now after loosing stuff over the years! I didn't know this auto-deletion was possible but will backup from now on for sure.

Comment: Yeah well it just means your human. It took three time of pour water in the instant pot without the stainless steel pot inside before developed habit of always cleaning stainless steel and put it back.  That's I have to do with backup and I don't like saving the entire sheet because it create another entire project for each backup making virtually hundred of projects out one.