# Is it possible to disable an Apps Script project or unlink it from a spreadsheet without deleting it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to the spreadsheet not run the Apps Script project, but I would like to keep it for possible future use.
Is it possible to disable an Apps Script project or unlink it from a spreadsheet without deleting it?

Comment: How about just never using the functions.  Please provide an explanation of what the project is so that we can answer the question properly.  We can't see what's your spreadsheet and we don't know what's in your mind.  You might like to learn how to write a better question.  SO has resource for that do some research on your own.

Comment: Cooper is right, please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because there are various ways we can approach this.

Comment: one method would be to "comment" them out using `/** <script> */`

Comment: [This link is for a script I wrote for backing up script files in standard text files.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656235/7215091)